# Optimization of CodeWars Python 3.6 code: Factorial decomposition

Tags: python

I need help about optimizing my codewars code that named factorial decomposing. The aim of the kata is to decompose n! (factorial n) into its prime factors. The result has to return string like that;

n = 12; decomp(12) -> "2^10 * 3^5 * 5^2 * 7 * 11"

My code is working properly and passing tests but when i try to attempt my code, i take time out error. Here is my try;

```py
def decomp(n):

    number_count = {2 : 1}
    return_str = ""

    def add_list(num):
        if num not in number_count:
            number_count[num] = 1
        else:
            number_count[num] += 1

    for x in range(n, 1, -1):
        add = False
        for y in range(1, x):
            if x == 1 or y == 1: continue
            a = True
            while a:
                if x % y == 0 and y != 1:
                    x = int(x / y)
                    add_list(y)
                else:
                    a = False
                    add = True

        if add and x != 1:
            add_list(x)

    number_count3 = {k: number_count[k] for k in sorted(number_count.keys())}

    for x, y in number_count3.items():
        if y == 1:
            return_str += str(x) + " * "
        else:
            return_str += str(x) + "^" + str(y) + " * "

    return return_str[:-3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve this be taking advantage of some number theory. For a factorial like `12!`, there will be

```
12//2 + 6//2 + 3//2
```

factors of two. Similar patterns will hold for all the other primes. So you can make a list of primes smaller than `n` and quickly decompose the exponent with something like:

```
def primes(n):
    n += 1
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]


def mults(n):
    res = []
    for p in primes(n):
        rest = n
        s = 0
        while rest >0:
            j = rest // p
            s += j
            rest = j
        if s > 1:
            res.append(f'{p}^{s}')
        else:
            res.append(str(p))
    return ' * '.join(res)

mults(16)
```

**Result**

```
'2^15 * 3^6 * 5^3 * 7^2 * 11 * 13'
```

Timing it compared to the original gives:

```
%timeit decomp(22)
54 µs ± 201 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit mults(22)
8.23 µs ± 30.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Which seems to be a decent improvement. The difference is more pronounced with larger `n`:

```
%timeit decomp(130)
823 µs ± 965 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit mults(130)
25.4 µs ± 73 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Awesome approach. Just one little problem here. "primes" function is not looking for n itself. If n is a prime number, the answer turns out with one multiplier. Such as, for 5 - "2^3 * 3" . It should be - "2^3 * 3 * 5". I solved this with adding n += 1 beginig of the prime fuction.

Comment: That’s a good catch @UysalAltas thanks. I’ll edit the answer when I’m back at a computer.